# UIBarButtonItem with transparence

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uibarbuttonitem

How to achieve button like this?

[image]

When I use `setBackgroundImage:forState:barMetrics:` and use pattern image, I got no border, shadow, gradient...

Also tried `setTintColor:` with `[UIColor clearColor]` which does not work at all.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try to set custom view for your UIBarButtonItem

```
UIBarButtonItem* bar = YOUR_BAR_BUTTON;
bar.customView = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:@"YOUR_IMAGE"] autorelease];
bar.customView.alpha = .5;
```

Comment: Alternately, you could just use a customView with a transparent png image (instead of setting customView.alpha).

Comment: Ok. But is there a solution without loosing that button mask? In this case I suppose I have to do this shiny border mask myself.

Comment: that solution actually doesn't work. did you try it?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what iOS version you're targeting but if you're on iOS 5 you can use the `UIAppearance` protocol to set a custom background image.

But beware, the background image must be stretchable!